# What is this port on an HP nc6220 docking station?

Tags: port, docking-station

I recently picked up an HP Compaq nc6220 and a docking station for it. Looking at the back, I saw a port that I didn't recognize:

[image: picture of docking station with unknown port identified]

It's too small to be a normal DE-9 connector. What is this port? What is it used for?

The docking station has HP product number: EN488AA

Comment: It looks the same as the connector in the back of a Dell lattitude docking station. Which is a custom plug to run to the rest of the dock where it connects to a power on/off/charging part. In other words: it might not be a standard connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a non standard video  output - the image above it is identical to the one I see on S-Video TV outs on laptops (VGA outs would have a symbol like a box with lines on either side).

A little research shows that [the manual](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01422464/c01422464.pdf) for what may be another dock refers to a similar port as a monitor stand port.

[image]

.

It is to connect to a HP Monitor Stand (PA507UT), unfortunately documentation for all the models is poor but I did find this [Link](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/archives_Canada/12075_ca_v3/12075_ca.HTML#Standard%20Features) and this [Link](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06c/A1-329290-329229-348718-348718-414357-3330896.html)
[image]

Comment: Correct document for the EN488AA here...http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13068_na/13068_na.html#HP Advanced Docking Station

Comment: I think you grabbed the wrong image...scroll down to the one labeled "HP docking station", my link paste gets truncated.

Comment: ahh. Too lazy for yet another screenshot, to fix it up again since this does show the answer clearly. Now I'm curious to what this port actually does - most of what I see seem to be simple, solid plastic stands..

Comment: Its to connect to an "HP Monitor Stand", scroll down for specs...http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/archives_Canada/12075_ca_v3/12075_ca.HTML#Standard%20Features

Comment: It is not 'non standard video out for certain' since it is not video out at all. Might want to edit that.

Comment: Added sufficient ambiguity since it may not be video out. Its definately the same symbol I see on video outs. Darn HP and their lack of idiotproof documentation ;p,

Comment: I checked my Dell Lattitude E series docking station. Same plug as the HP one (might be standarised after all). The plug controls a power button on a laptop docking station (on/off, as well a LED if the power is turned on).

Answer (score 4):

I can shed light on this whole thing: Here is a product link:

https://hinta.fi/24258/hp-lcd-monitor-stand/tuotetiedot

It is a cable for the LEDs on the HP monitor stand. Henc why it called monitor stand port.

As per the description in the product details in the link, it says that the monitor stand lights up when laptop on on and docked etc. just like the docking station does. It is because when it is in the stand, you couldn’t see the lights on the docking station as it sits at the back, under the monitor.

Took me alot of research and thought to figure this out!